# How do I expand C++ macro to a comma delimited list of arguments?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Given the following macros expansions:

```
#define process_detail(name, arg1, arg2, arg3) name,arg1,arg2,arg3
#define process(x) process_detail(expand_args(x)))
```

I would like to expand arg0 (arg1, arg2, arg3) to four arguments arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3 
How to write the expand_args(...) macro?

e.g.  in the above example, calling process(a(b,c,d)) should expand to a,b,c,d
Basically, the expand_args() macro should remove the enclosed parenthesis and insert a comma after the first value.

Comment: Anything starting with a double underscore is reserved; don't do that.

Comment: You're assuming it's possible.   It isn't.   You can make `a` a macro, using `#define a(b,c,d) a,b,c,d`, but there is no way another macro can expand it's argument as you ask.

Comment: Create multiple macros process1, process2, etc. up to the max number of args that you need.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- anything **containing** two consecutive underscores is reserved, as is any name that **begins with** an underscore followed by a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks Pepe, I just edited the question to get rid of the underscores. My question is mainly about the macro expansion itself, how to remove the enclosed parenthesis in the argument.